# Add element to a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to add an element to a json file in python but I am not able to do it.

This is what I tried untill now (with some variation which I deleted):

```
import json

data = [ { 'a':'A', 'b':(2, 4), 'c':3.0 } ]
print 'DATA:', repr(data)

var = 2.4
data.append({'f':var})
print 'JSON', json.dumps(data)
```

But, what I get is:

```
DATA: [{'a': 'A', 'c': 3.0, 'b': (2, 4)}]
JSON [{"a": "A", "c": 3.0, "b": [2, 4]}, {"f": 2.4}]
```

Which is fine because I also need this to add a new row instead an element but I want to get something like this:

```
[{'a': 'A', 'c': 3.0, 'b': (2, 4), "f":2.4}]
```

How should I add the new element?

Comment: I think the thing to understand here is that you have in your list a dict embedded in it, when you append you add a new element which is a new dict. If you want to add to the dict then you should access the dict and add the new element as @Jayanth has shown

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can do this.

```
data[0]['f'] = var
```

Comment: What if 'f' doesn't exist, then you have a key error

Comment: @LawrenceDeSouza Look at the example code: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 19):

One possible issue I see is you set your JSON unconventionally within an array/list object. I would recommend using JSON in its most accepted form, i.e.:

```
test_json = { "a": 1, "b": 2}
```

Once you do this, adding a json element only involves the following line:

```
test_json["c"] = 3
```

This will result in:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Afterwards, you can add that json back into an array or a list of that is desired.

Comment: What if I want to add 3 into b ?
{'a': 1, 'b': 2,3}    how can it be done ?

Answer (score 6):

alternatively you can do

```
iter(data).next()['f'] = var
```