# Troubleshoot JSON Parsing/Adding Property

Tags: python, json

I have a json whose first few lines are:

```
{
"type": "Topology",
"objects": {
    "counties": {
        "type": "GeometryCollection",
        "bbox": [-179.1473399999999, 17.67439566600018, 179.7784800000003, 71.38921046500008],
        "geometries": [{
                    "type": "MultiPolygon",
                    "id": 53073,
                    "arcs": [
                        [
                            [0, 1, 2]
                        ]
                    ]
                },
```

I built a python dictionary from that data as follows:

```
import json
with open('us.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

It's a very long json (each county in the US). Yet when I run: `len(data)` it returns 4. I was a bit confused by that. So I set out to probe further and explore the data:

```
data['id']
data['geometry']
```

both of which return key errors. Yet I know that this json file is defined for those properties. In fact, that's all the json is, its the id for each county 'id' and a series of polygon coordinates for each county 'geometry'. Entering `data` does indeed return the whole json, and I can see the properties that way, but that doesn't help much.

My ultimate aim is to add a property to the json file, somewhat similar to this:

[Add element to a json in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296496/add-element-to-a-json-in-python)

The difference is I'm adding a property that is from a tsv. If you'd like all the details you may find my json and tsv here:

https://gist.github.com/diggetybo/ca9d3c2fed76ddc7185cf966a65b8718

For clarity, let me summarize what I'm asking:

**My question is**: Why can't I access the properties in the above way? Can someone provide a way to access the properties I'm interested in ('id','geometries') Or better yet, demonstrate how to add a property?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*json.load*

> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a
>   JSON document) to a **Python object** using this conversion table.

`[]` are for lists and `{}` are for dictionaries.So this is an example  to get `id`:

```
with open("us.json") as f:
    c=json.load(f)
    for i in  c["objects"]["counties"]["geometries"]:
        print i["id"]
```

And the structure of your data is like this:

```
   { 
      "type":"xx",
      "objects":"xx",
      "arcs":"xx",
      "transform":"xx"
    }
```

So the length of `data` is 4.You can append data or add a new element just like using `list` and `dict`.See more details from [Json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The documentation really confused me, thank you for clearing up that. With your example I was able to slice into a single 'id' with: `data['objects']['counties']['geometries'][0]['id']`. That's a huge step for me. lets say I loaded the tsv as `data2` and I want to add name to the json. Am I right to use `data['objects']['counties']['geometries']['name']=data2['name']`?

Comment: Or is the for loop also the best way to go for adding to the json?

Comment: Let's try to simplify it.If you want to add some element to every dict or list,you should use loop,if not you can just append a new element to list.`data['objects']['counties']['geometries']` is a list,so you can append element,but `data['objects']['counties']['geometries'][0]` is an element of the list,and it is a dict,so you can add `name` as a key and set a value like  `data['objects']['counties']['geometries'][0]['name']="Mike"`

Comment: @ArashHowaida I suggest you read [Python datastructures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and just have a try.