# Is there any way to modify a JSON with Python?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to modify a JSON with Python but I can not do it correctly.

I have tried the module that comes with Python by default to deal with JSON but I can not do the next step.

The JSON to modify is this:

```
{
    "uuid":"789ce6ed-ec0f-418b-8fad-6ba64cb8bd70",
    "assetTemplate":[
        {
            "id":14,
            "name":"Template-conectividad"
        },
        {
            "id":54,
            "name":"Template-discos-agata"
        },
        {
            "id":17,
            "name":"Template-servidor-linux"
        }
    ],
    "info":null
}
```

And it should look like this:

```
{
    "uuid":"789ce6ed-ec0f-418b-8fad-6ba64cb8bd70",
    "assetTemplate":[
        {
            "id":54,
            "name":"Template-discos-agata"
        },
        {
            "id":17,
            "name":"Template-servidor-linux"
        },
        {
            "id":85,
            "name":"Template-conectividad-test"
        }
    ],
    "info":null
}
```

This is what I tried to remove the part I do not want but I have the part to insert the new data:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

# We load JSON to modify

x = '{"uuid":"789ce6ed-ec0f-418b-8fad-6ba64cb8bd70","assetTemplate":[{"id":14,"name":"Template-conectividad"},{"id":54,"name":"Template-discos-agata"},{"id":17,"name":"Template-servidor-linux"}],"info":null}'

y = json.loads(x)

obj = y["assetTemplate"]

# We remove the object that we dont want

for i in range(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]['id'] == 14:
        del obj[i]
        break

print(obj)

# We make output of what has been achieved

x = json.dumps(y)

print(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296496/add-element-to-a-json-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a json, its contents are loaded as dictionaries (`{}` with contents as `key:value`) and lists (`[]`).

That means `obj` is a normal list - which you already kinda know because you iterate over it.

Because it's a normal list, you can just `.append` what you want as a dictionary, so:

```
d={"id":85,"name":"Template-conectividad-test"}
obj.append(d)
```

Comment: You can also use `obj.insert(0, d)` if you want to insert the new entry at index 0 (or any other index). `list.append` always puts the new item at the end of the list.