# Add a new entry to a json file in Python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have a json file that works fine, I have a bot command on discord that displays a random entry from it.

The next command I would like to write is on how to add a new entry so that I don't need to do it manually through Atom.

```
async def addquote(self, ctx, message):
    with open('quotes.json','r') as f:
        quote = json.load(f)
    #quote[str(message)] =
    with open('quotes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(quote, f)
    await ctx.send('Quote added.')
```

The commented # line is where I'm struggling the most I think.

[Jsonfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC3dR.png)

Here's a screenshot of the jsonfile, how it looks. I would like to add more "quotes" to it with that function

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Samy. I dont know Python, but this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296496/add-element-to-a-json-in-python) might help you.

Comment: `quote['quote'] = str(message)` works?

Comment: @D.Seah hello thank you for your help, I just tried that but it didn't work. The code runs, it sends the end message but json file doesn't get modified

Comment: when you have `quote = json.load(f)`. What is `quote`? is it a `dict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using a list instead of a dictionary in my JSON.

```
async def addquote(self, ctx, *, message):
        with open('quotes.json','r') as f:
            quote = json.load(f)
        quote.append(message)
        with open('quotes.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(quote, f)
        await ctx.send('Quote added.')
```

The quote.json was cleared and the content was only []
Then writing to it worked.

Answer (score 0):

These code worked on my side:

```py
import json
with open('quotes.json','r') as f:
    quote = json.load(f)
print(quote)
quote['Quote'].append({
    'quote':"test"
})
with open('prefises.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(quote, f)
```

with the quotes.json:

```
{"Quote":[]}
```

and the prefises.json:

```
{"Quote": [{"quote": "test"}]}
```

Comment: Did you mean `quote['Quote'].append({'quote':str(message)})` ? And it didn't work as well unfortunately

Comment: Sorry there is a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying your method. Why do I need a prefix.json ? `with open('quotes.json','r') as f:
            quote = json.load(f)
        quote['Quote'].append({
            'quote':"test"
        })
        with open('prefises.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(quote, f)
        await ctx.send('Quote added.')` I have this but couldn't get it to work yet

Comment: Oh lord, I just noticed that I have this line myself. Sorry it was late at night ah. I don't know why I put this prefises.json line. I only need one json, the one with the quotes